# RegisterClass returns 0

Tags: c, winapi

I have written a small program that simply creates a window application with one tab control in it. However, when I run the program, a message box appears indicating that the RegisterClassA function has failed with an error code of 0.

The code;

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, \
             HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, \
             PWSTR pCmdLine, \
             int nCmdShow){

 //Variable declarations
 INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX *tmpiccex = 0;
 HWND hwindow = 0;
 HWND tbcontrol = 0;
 WNDCLASSA winclass;
 MSG tmpmsg;
 char *tmpstr = 0;
 int tmpn = 0;
 int ret = 0;

 //Argument checks

 //Initializations

 //Main logic

 //Allocate memory for one INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX.
 tmpiccex = (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX*)calloc(1, sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX));

 //Set the members of the new tmpiccex
 //object.
 tmpiccex->dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
 tmpiccex->dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;

 //Load the Common Controls DLL and register
 //some common controls.
 InitCommonControlsEx(tmpiccex);

 //Allocate memory to tmpstr.
 tmpstr = (char*)calloc(512, sizeof(char));

 //Initialize the window class.
 winclass.lpfnWndProc = WinProc1;
 winclass.hInstance = hInstance;
 winclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
 winclass.lpszClassName = "mwClass";
 winclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
 winclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
 winclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
 winclass.style = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_OWNDC | \
            CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
            
 //Register the window class.
 ret = RegisterClassA(&winclass);
 if(ret == 0){
  tmpn = GetLastError();
  sprintf(tmpstr, "Registering the window failed.\nFunction returned %d.", tmpn);
  MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
         "Error", MB_OK);
 }

 //Create the window.
 hwindow = CreateWindowA("mwClass", \
                     "Experimenting with windows", \
                     WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | \
                 WS_THICKFRAME | WS_CAPTION | \
                 WS_SYSMENU, \
                     CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                 CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                 712, \
                 569, \
                     NULL, \
                     NULL, \
                     hInstance, \
                     NULL);
 if(hwindow == NULL){
  tmpn = GetLastError();
  sprintf(tmpstr, "Creating the window failed.\nFunction returned %d.", tmpn);
  MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
         "Error", MB_OK);
  return TFAILED;
 }
 
 //Show the window.
 ShowWindow(hwindow, SW_NORMAL);

 //Create a tab control.
 tbcontrol = CreateWindowA(WC_TABCONTROL, \
                     "", \
                     WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, \
                     CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                 CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                 680, \
                 488, \
                     hwindow, \
                     NULL, \
                     hInstance, \
                     NULL);
 if(tbcontrol == NULL){
  tmpn = GetLastError();
  sprintf(tmpstr, "Creating the tab control failed.\nFunction returned %d.", tmpn);
  MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
         "Error", MB_OK);
  return TFAILED;
 }

 //Show the window.
 ShowWindow(tbcontrol, SW_NORMAL);

 //Process window messages.
 while(TTRUE){
  
  //Wait for a message to enter the
  //queue.
  ret = GetMessage(&tmpmsg, \
         NULL, \
         0, \
         0);

  if(ret > 0){

   //Translate the message.
   TranslateMessage(&tmpmsg);

   //Dispatch the message by
   //calling the window pro-
   //cedure.
   DispatchMessage(&tmpmsg);

  }else{

   MessageBox(NULL, "Exiting.", \
          "Success", MB_OK);

   //Exit the while loop.
   break;

  } //EndIf

 } //End while loop.

 //Free variables

 //Returns
 return TSUCCESS;

}
```

I did not include the code for the window procedure so that more concentration can be made on where the error is happening.

I expected the program to display a window application with a tab control inside.

Comment: What's `WinProc1` and where do you create it? In general all CreateWindow stuff apart from the window itself typically goes into `WM_CREATE` in the Wndproc.

Comment: If you don't initialize the struct then you have to set *all* of the fields in the WNDCLASSA struct.

Comment: @Lundin If window class registration fails, then it's not very interesting to want to see the window procedure. Surely, no one is going to run it anyway.

Comment: @IInspectable The point is that the registration might fail because it gets passed invalid parameters.

Comment: @Lundin Unless `WinProc1` is a null pointer, there's little the system can do to validate the pointer. And yes, window class registration fails because it gets invalid parameters. But it's not the parameters that are actually being set...

Comment: @IInspectable There's plenty that the system could do to validate the pointer, but if it chose to do that or not is another story. Computers/MMUs utilize virtual memory to allocate executable code and data is different regions. An OS may split the address space in kernel vs user addresses and it may also map a process' memory after certain rules.

Comment: If you change the code to `static WNDCLASSA winclass;` does everything magically start working?

Comment: @Lundin Regardless of whether `WinProc1` represents a valid pointer or not, any talk about `WM_CREATE` is moot, since no one is going to send *any* messages to a window procedure when window class registration fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the initialization of winclass. The cbClsExtra and cbWndExtra properties had to be set to zero (0).